# Redirect from one page to another along with some POST data in Flask

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I am working on a Flask project. After successful execution of login function, it should redirect on home page with some data. The data should be send by post. How can this be done??

Comment: You can use ```redirect``` after success login. For send data look ```Response``` argument

Comment: that I am doing. I cant figure out how to attach data to it. I have tried it with get request but dont know what to do for POST request.

Comment: so, you should to use ```url_for("url", data=data)```, so in your other view use ```request.args['data']``` thus, should work fine, tell me please.

Comment: it says `TypeError: redirect() got an unexpected keyword argument 'user_id'` when i gave the commad: `redirect(url_for('mainpage'),user_id=res['_id'])`

Comment: it is giving 405 error code because it takes it as GET request

Answer (score 1):

For send data after successful login you can use `url_for` within of `redirect` something as this:

```
@app.route('/login', methods = ['POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.form.get("username") == 'admin':
        return redirect(url_for('success',data=request.form.get("data")),code=307)
    else:
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

After success login you can use your data to send with `data=data`, so in your other view you get that data.

```
@app.route("/test/argument", methods=['POST'])
def success():
    messages = request.form.get('data')  # counterpart for url_for()
    return messages
```

Comment: it is giving 405 error code because it takes it as GET request

Comment: after putting `code=307` in argument of redirect, it still makes an get request but starts to work. I dont want GET request. I want it to be POST

Comment: @JatinBhola I updated my answer with a example with login this work fine for me, check out and you tell me anything.

Comment: missing last quote on redirect, and it sends GET param, not POST